# Font cannot be extracted by PDFMiner

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, pdfminer

I am converting some pdf reports to plain text using PDFMiner and a bunch of my input pdfs just come out with a couple of recognised lines and then a list of (cid:%d) a little like this...

> Inspection report
>
> (cid:4)(cid:5)(cid:6)(cid:7)(cid:8)(cid:9)
>   (cid:10)(cid:9)(cid:11)(cid:9)(cid:12)(cid:9)(cid:5)(cid:13)(cid:9)
>   (cid:14)(cid:8)(cid:15)(cid:16)(cid:9)(cid:12)
>   (cid:17)(cid:18)(cid:13)(cid:19)(cid:20)
>   (cid:21)(cid:8)(cid:22)(cid:23)(cid:18)(cid:12)(cid:6)(cid:22)(cid:24)
>   (cid:25)(cid:5)(cid:26)(cid:27)(cid:9)(cid:13)(cid:22)(cid:6)(cid:18)(cid:5)
>   (cid:5)(cid:8)(cid:15)(cid:16)(cid:9)(cid:12)

Checking it out I think the problem is the bulk of the document is in a font that is resisting being extracted. Debugging the problem has been kind of strange because the font seemed to change over night (don't ask how, it just did).

I'm not sure what might be significant but today the font has properties:

name = 'font0000000018f29a3e' -
cidcoding = 'Adobe-Identity'- unicode_map = 'UnicodeMap: /Adobe-Identity-UCS'  - unicode_map.cid2unichr = {}

I'm using 2.7 on a mac and have tried a few things

1. PyPDF2
2. Copying and pasting into textedit (characters are blank)
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling with cmaps rebuilt
4. Turning the machine off and then on again

For reference the reports are all of similar form one of which can be found here.

http://www.ofsted.gov.uk/provider/files/959173/urn/118074.pdf

The problem applies to all reports published prior to September 2010

Comment: Keep in mind that what you are doing may be illegal. The author of the document may have purchased a license for the font being used (several fonts are included for instance when you buy Adobe InDesign), but that does not mean the license for that font is transferred to you (the consumer of the document). Extracting the font enables you to reproduce and use it, which may violate copyright law.

Comment: @JorisSchellekens Can you look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773909/what-to-do-with-cids-in-text-extracted-by-pdfminer) question?